# VS Build Tools 2019 Error in Windows Container

Tags: visual-studio, docker, msbuild, windows-container, windows-server-2019

Following this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/build-tools-container?view=vs-2019), if I *remove* the installPath and use the default MsBuild Visual Studio location, I get the following error.

> *Error: Visual Studio Build Tools 2019 (2) is already installed*

I built a similar container a few weeks back and everything worked, however something appears to have moved and I'm unable to work out what.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding the modify parameter to the vs_BuildTools.exe command resolves this issue. Unfortunately it forces an installPath to be included but can be set to the default location.

Comment: Hi Neil, thanks for your sharing and you can consider marking your reply as answer and that will help other community members who easier search this useful information!